# Trying to create a dataframe with the column as a specific value in my dataset

Tags: r

I have this dataset, foo:

```
foo
         assets.198     assets.attributable          assets.current 
               0.98                    0.98                    0.98
```

I am trying to create a dataframe that has the names, such as assets.calculated, as the row names, and the numbers such as 0.96 as the column values. I've tried: 
foo1 <- data.frame(words = names(foo), correlation = )

What should I put in as equal to correlation?

I'm beginning with R, and am still trying to figure out to inspect foo and see what type of data I have as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `foo[1, ]`. Or any other row number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that foo is a named vector, you can use `enframe()` from the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

bar  <- enframe(foo)

bar

    # A tibble: 3 x 2
                 name value
                <chr> <dbl>
1          assets.198  0.98
2 assets.attributable  0.98
3      assets.current  0.98
```